# how drop rows if dtype is int in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to drop rows from a dataframe if it's value's datatype is `int`

Here's the code:-

```
dfd={'a':1,'b':'a','c':56,'d':'ok'}

dataframes=pd.DataFrame(dfd.items())

#if value is integer drop

for line in dataframes.index:
    if(type(dataframes['value'][line])==int):
        dataframes.drop(dataframes['value'][line],inplace=True)
```

I'm expecting:-

```
   key value
   b   d
   a   ok
```

But get an error

> KeyError: 'value'

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `dtype` applies to the *column* not the individual rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is necessary set columns names, e.g. by DataFrame cosntructor:

```
dataframes=pd.DataFrame(dfd.items(), columns=['key','value'])

print (dataframes)
  key value
0   a     1
1   b     a
2   c    56
3   d    ok
```

And then convert values to numeric by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and `errors='coerce'`, if no numeric is returned missing value, so filter by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for non numeric rows:

```
df = dataframes[pd.to_numeric(dataframes['value'], errors='coerce').isna()]
print (df)
  key value
1   b     a
3   d    ok
```

Another idea if need filter only integers:

```
df = dataframes[dataframes['value'].apply(lambda x: not isinstance(x, int))]
```

Or:

```
df = dataframes[dataframes['value'].apply(type) != int]
```

---

```
print (df)
  key value
1   b     a
3   d    ok
```